# Using a union to read a char array as an unsigned long int

Tags: arrays, char, union, long-integer, unsigned

As the title hints, essentially I convert a char array into an unsigned long int (or rather, read as an unsigned long int) by means of a Union.

```
union {
    char buffer[8];
    unsigned long int buffer_ui;
} char_array_ui;
```

I read 8 chars into the char array, then later on return the value of those 8 chars as an unsigned long int. (For those curious, it is because I am reading chars from /dev/urandom).
Is this safe to do? Is there anything that could potentially go in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to be aware of:

- It's correct as long as the size of `unsigned long` is 8 bytes - might not be so on every platform.
- Endianness might be different on various platforms, thus producing different results. If you read data as an `unsigned long` it's automatically taken care of to produce the correct result but if you read it byte after byte, the order is the way you store the bytes.

Comment: If it's C++11, `long long int` is guaranteed to be 64-bit, so in that case you want `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: @TimothyShields I think the question was edited from `unsigned long long` to `unsigned long` so I've changed the answer as well. In any case, `long long int` has **minimum** 64bit size.

Comment: Thanks - but please, you can clearly see I haven't edited my question!

Comment: @JessMcintosh ok, the answer is the same. BTW, editing the question close to posting not always shown as edit at SO